# Is it possible for us to see the primary voting details of the last election (2013) by phase?

Tags: support, election

I remember that I was able to view the nomination phase in all it's glory past the election (by clicking on a comment notification to my nomination).

I've lost that link in the ether of my activity. I was wondering if there's an easier way to get that page?

Just wanted to see how bad I lost :).

**I am looking to know the voting numbers in the primary phase for ALL candidates**, not just the top 10 (i.e. I want to see exactly where I came).

Comment: Hmm. http://stackoverflow.com/election seems to be a good start!

Comment: @J.Steen Yeah it's a good start thanks, but I wanted the voting numbers for ALL candidates (there's only the top 10 listed) :)

Answer (score 7):

You can find the original election page at:

https://stackoverflow.com/election/4

with primary voting tallies still available on the [primaries tab](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4?tab=primary). Unfortunately that only shows the top 10 candidates, those that went on to the election phase.

This is linked from both http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stackoverflow and https://stackoverflow.com/election.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, although it doesn't show vote numbers? Are they purposefully hidden?

Comment: @mattytommo: You are not looking at the correct tab; click 'primaries' for primary voting numbers. Nomination *has* no votes.

Comment: Doh yeah, thanks. Although it only shows the top 10 people? Primaries started with everyone?

Comment: @mattytommo: Ah, indeed, only the top 10 that went on to the election phase are still listed there.

Comment: @mattytommo: but yes, the primaries included everyone, there were fewer than 30 nominations.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am looking for, votes for everyone (all 27)